# Trying to read excel file with epplus and getting System.NullException error?

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

### Edit

Based on the replies below, the error I am experiencing may or may not be causing my inability to read my excel file. That is, I am not getting data from the line `worksheet.Cells[row,col].Value` in my for loop given below.

### Problem

I am trying to return a DataTable with information from an excel file. Specifically, it is an xlsx file from 2013 excel I believe. Please see the code below:

```
private DataTable ImportToDataTable(string Path)
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(Path);

            if(!fi.Exists)
            {
                throw new Exception("File " + Path + " Does not exist.");
            }

            using (ExcelPackage xlPackage = new ExcelPackage(fi))
            {
                //Get the worksheet in the workbook 
                ExcelWorksheet worksheet = xlPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.First();

                //Obtain the worksheet size 
                ExcelCellAddress startCell = worksheet.Dimension.Start;
                ExcelCellAddress endCell = worksheet.Dimension.End;

                //Create the data column 
                for(int col = startCell.Column; col <= endCell.Column; col++)
                {
                    dt.Columns.Add(col.ToString());
                }


                for(int row = startCell.Row; row <= endCell.Row; row++)
                {
                    DataRow dr = dt.NewRow(); //Create a row
                    int i = 0; 
                    for(int col = startCell.Column; col <= endCell.Column; col++)
                    {
                        dr[i++] = worksheet.Cells[row, col].Value.ToString();
                    }
                    dt.Rows.Add(dr);

                }
            }

            return dt;


        }
```

### Error

This is where things get weird. I can see the proper value in `startCell` and `endCell`. However, when I look at `worksheet` I take a peek under `Cells` and I see something I don't understand:

```
worksheet.Cells.Current' threw an exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException
```

### Attempts

- Reformatting my excel with general fields.
- Making sure no field in my excel was empty
- RTFM'ed epplus documentation. Nothing suggestive of this error.
- Looked at EPPlus errors on stackoverflow. My problem is unique.

Honestly, I am having trouble figuring out what this error is really saying? Is something wrong with my format? Is something wrong with epplus? I have read on here people had no problems with 2013 xlsx with eeplus and I am only trying to parse the excel file by row. If someone could help me shed light on what this error means and how to rectify it. I would be most grateful. I've spent quite a long time trying to figure this out.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Comment: Current might implicate you to mark a range!?, and after that you have a current cell.   Does this affect your program cant ,see any access to Current , or is it just bothering you that something in the Cells object throws exception when you inspect it? wich in fact is very common in .net environment

Comment: Yes, this does affect my program. I am unable to see `Value` when enumerating in the loop below. I thought this error was the cause.

Comment: @doctor This is not a replicate. I'm not asking why I have a null here as much as why it is causing my enumeration on the bottom to fail. I cannot see `Value`. I will edit question to be more precise. Thanks. :)

Comment: Thank you everyone for your replies so far. Upvotes for all for participating.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like @Thorians said, current is really meant to use when you enumerating the cells.  If you want to use it in purest form and actually be able to call `current` then you would need something like this:

```
using (var pck = new ExcelPackage(existingFile))
{
    var worksheet = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.First();

    //this is important to hold onto the range reference
    var cells = worksheet.Cells;

    //this is important to start the cellEnum object (the Enumerator)
    cells.Reset();

    //Can now loop the enumerator
    while (cells.MoveNext())
    {
        //Current can now be used thanks to MoveNext
        Console.WriteLine("Cell [{0}, {1}] = {2}"
            , cells.Current.Start.Row
            , cells.Current.Start.Column
            , cells.Current.Value);
    }
}
```

Note that you have to create a kind of `local` collection `cells` for this to work properly.  Otherwise `Current` will be null if you tried `worksheet.cells.current'

But it would be simpler to use a `ForEach` and have the CLR do the work for you.

---

UPDATE: Based on comments.  Your code should work fine as is, could it be your excel file:

```
[TestMethod]
public void Current_Cell_Test()
{
    //http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32516676/trying-to-read-excel-file-with-epplus-and-getting-system-nullexception-error

    //Throw in some data
    var datatable = new DataTable("tblData");
    datatable.Columns.AddRange(new[] { new DataColumn("Col1", typeof (int)), new DataColumn("Col2", typeof (int)),new DataColumn("Col3", typeof (object)) });

    for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        var row = datatable.NewRow(); row[0] = i; row[1] = i * 10; row[2] = Path.GetRandomFileName(); datatable.Rows.Add(row);
    }

    //Create a test file
    var fi = new FileInfo(@"c:\temp\test1.xlsx");
    if (fi.Exists)
        fi.Delete();

    using (var pck = new ExcelPackage(fi))
    {
        var worksheet = pck.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Sheet1");
        worksheet.Cells.LoadFromDataTable(datatable, true);
        pck.Save();
    }

    var dt = new DataTable();

    using (ExcelPackage xlPackage = new ExcelPackage(fi))
    {
        //Get the worksheet in the workbook 
        ExcelWorksheet worksheet = xlPackage.Workbook.Worksheets.First();

        //Obtain the worksheet size 
        ExcelCellAddress startCell = worksheet.Dimension.Start;
        ExcelCellAddress endCell = worksheet.Dimension.End;

        //Create the data column 
        for (int col = startCell.Column; col <= endCell.Column; col++)
        {
            dt.Columns.Add(col.ToString());
        }


        for (int row = startCell.Row; row <= endCell.Row; row++)
        {
            DataRow dr = dt.NewRow(); //Create a row
            int i = 0;
            for (int col = startCell.Column; col <= endCell.Column; col++)
            {
                dr[i++] = worksheet.Cells[row, col].Value.ToString();
            }
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);

        }
    }

    Console.Write("{{dt Rows: {0} Columns: {1}}}", dt.Rows.Count, dt.Columns.Count);
}
```

Give this in the output:

```
{Rows: 11, Columns: 3}
```

Comment: Thanks. You are right. I am trying to enumerate through my cells as seen above in my code, but I fail. Specifically `dr[i++] = worksheet.Cells[row, col].Value` does not either. Is this related to `Current` or do I really have a separate problem and didn't realize it?

Comment: @hlyates  Humm..thats interesting.  Your code should work as is.  Seem my update above.  What is your exact error?

Answer (score 3):

When we give:

```
dr[i++] = worksheet.Cells[row, col].Value.ToString();
```

it search for value at that column, if the column is empty, it gives Null reference error.

Try instead:

```
dr[i++] = worksheet.Cells[row, col].Text;
```

Hope this will help

Answer (score 1):

Current is the current range when enumerating.

there is nothing wrong with this throwing an exception in debugging inspection when it is not being used within an enumerating scope.

code sample:

```
var range = ws.Cells[1,1,1,100];
foreach (var cell in range)
{
    var a =  range.Current.Value;  // a is same as b
    var b = cell.Value;         
}
```

Comment: Seems that I cannot access my cells when enumerating when I use `worksheet.Cells[row,col].value`. If I am understanding you correctly, this is because I did not use a `range` appropriately?

Comment: yes, And I think you should avoid Current , and use cell instead

Answer (score 0):

I am also getting same issue while reading excel file and none of the solution provided worked for me. Here is working code:

```
public void readXLS(string FilePath)
{
    FileInfo existingFile = new FileInfo(FilePath);
    using (ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(existingFile))
    {
        //get the first worksheet in the workbook
        ExcelWorksheet worksheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets[1];
        int colCount = worksheet.Dimension.End.Column;  //get Column Count
        int rowCount = worksheet.Dimension.End.Row;     //get row count
        for (int row = 1; row <= rowCount; row++)
        {
            for (int col = 1; col <= colCount; col++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(" Row:" + row + " column:" + col + " Value:" + worksheet.Cells[row, col].Value.ToString().Trim());
            }
        }
    }
}
```